# Longest sequence from an array such that following relation holds X[ i ] = X[ i-1 ] + X [ i-2 ]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sequence, dynamic-programming

This question was asked in an exam. We have given an array of size n.

We need to find longest sequence such that it holds following relationship

if X is longest sequence than:

```
       X[i] = X[i-1] + X[i-2]
```

Example: a= [3,2,7,13,5,8,11,19]

than X = [2,3,5,8,13]

I am thinking of some Dynamic logic but i am not able to derive the relation.

Comment: `Sequence` usually assumes no reordering. What is exact problem formulation?

Comment: @MBo i believe *subsequence* means no reordering, but if we need to create new *sequence* we can use any order.

Comment: Sequence with respect to an input array does have to honor the order of the input array I presume. In your case it seems you need a set of numbers in the increasing order from the array that satisfies a particular relation.

Comment: Yes sequence corresponds to set.

Comment: Not really, sequence is order, that's why you can index it like `X[i]`. Usually, when we are told to find subsequence this means that it should preserve order of initial, e.g. `1,3` is subsequence of `1,2,3`, but `3,1` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you sort it to get `2,3,5,7,8,11,13,19`.

Next you start with `2`, `3` and check if their sum is in the array, it is there, so proceed with `3`, `5`, then `5`, `8`, then `8`, `13`. As soon as you have failed you backtrack and start again.

You might want to use hash map to speed-up lookup in the array or just binary search in the array's leftover.

Comment: As hash map will take space so it will take O( n * n ) or if we go binary search the time complexity will be                                                                                                                O( n * n * log(n) ) right ??

Comment: @Jagan_ A hash map will take O(n) space. And that's pretty hard to compute time complexity for this algorithm. Though to enumerate all such sequences might take O(n^3) in case if we have array of all zeroes, but we don't need to enumerate. I believe this algorithm works fast in practice.